# Lucene Duplicated results / spaces in text search

Tags: lucene.net

I’m actually using Lucene 2.9.4.1 and everything works just fine if I search for something that exists just once in the same line.
Per instance, if Lucene find the same string that I’m looking for in the same line, I have duplicated (or more) results.

```
I’m actually using the following BooleanQuery: 
booleanQuery.Add(new TermQuery(new Term(propertyInfo.Name, textSearch)), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
```

The second issue is about searching by something with spaces like “hello world”: never works.

Can anyone advise me or help me with these two malfunctioning features, please?

Thank you so much in advance,
Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

Well, I just found the answer that solved both of my issues =)

I was using this:

```
BooleanQuery booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();
PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos = typeof(T).GetProperties();
foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in propertyInfos)
{
    booleanQuery.Add(new TermQuery(new Term(propertyInfo.Name, textSearch)), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
}
```

And now I use this:

```
var booleanQuery = new BooleanQuery();
textSearch = QueryParser.Escape(textSearch.Trim().ToLower());

string[] properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().Select(x => x.Name).ToArray();

Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(global::Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29);
MultiFieldQueryParser titleParser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29, properties, analyzer);
Query titleQuery = titleParser.Parse(textSearch);

booleanQuery.Add(titleQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
```

It seems that **Analyzer** and **MultiFieldQueryParser** are the solution for my problems: no more duplicated results, I can search by something with spaces and … the performance as significantly raised up (faster results) =)